# Syntax specific settings in sublime-project settings file

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

A sublime-settings file enforces settings on a per-project basis:

```
{
    "folders": [ ... ]
    "settings":
    {
        "tab_size": 4
    }
}
```

How is it possible to use syntax specific settings in this file, for example to set a `tab_size` of 2 only for `*.js` files?

Comment: Are you trying to set these settings for a particular **project** (`.sublime-project` settings file) or globally for any `.js` file, regardless of its origin?

Comment: For any `.js` file in this project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't set language-exclusive settings directly in your user `Preferences.sublime-settings` file. However, when editing a file of a given type, you can create a settings file limited only to that type with the menu item `Preferences -> Settings–More -> Syntax Specific – User`.

This new file will appear in your `Packages/User` directory with a name matching its language, e.g. `Markdown.sublime-settings` would be a Markdown-specific settings file.

Comment: Except that copying such a file to your project isn't picked up. You cannot set this *per project*, it appears.

Answer (score 4):

You could checkout [.editorconfig](http://editorconfig.org).

Basically an .editorconfig file would look like,

```
# editorconfig.org

# top-most EditorConfig file
root = true

# Unix-style newlines with a newline ending every file
[*]
end_of_line = lf
insert_final_newline = true

# Matches multiple files with brace expansion notation
# Set default charset
[*.{js,py}]
charset = utf-8

# 4 space indentation
[*.py]
indent_style = space
indent_size = 4

# Tab indentation (no size specified)
[Makefile]
indent_style = tab

# Indentation override for all JS under lib directory
[lib/**.js]
indent_style = space
indent_size = 2

# Matches the exact files either package.json or .travis.yml
[{package.json,.travis.yml}]
indent_style = space
indent_size = 2
```

There's even a nice Sublime Text package that automatically reads and understands them. Just throw your .editorconfig in version control and you're ready to go.