# How to make Sublime 3 open .js files with JSX syntax

Tags: sublimetext3, jsx, syntax-highlighting, editorconfig

I'm using Sublime 3 on MacOS 10.15.7 and I'm working on a React project.

I have a package installed for JSX syntax highlighting, and it works fine if I manually set it after opening the file. By default, it starts with JavaScript highlighting every time I open the files because my component files have .js extensions. (There are reasons for this.) Is there a way for me to configure Sublime to open these project files with JSX highlighting automatically? If it helps, I also use [editorconfig](https://editorconfig.org/).

NOTE: I don't want to force Sublime to globally open ANY js file as JSX because that will cause the reverse problem with all my Node.js / JavaScript projects. I need a solution that is project-specific.

Thanks in advance!

Sort of related to: [Syntax specific settings in sublime-project settings file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19904581/syntax-specific-settings-in-sublime-project-settings-file)

Comment: what were the reasons for using the native `.js` extension with third-party React files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With further digging, I found this package which appears to enable this feature: https://github.com/reywood/sublime-project-specific-syntax

But I'd prefer a native solution, if possible.

Comment: What do you mean by a "native solution"?

Comment: @MattDMo I meant a solution that didn't require another package. Something "natively" supported by Sublime.

Comment: Packages *are* natively supported by Sublime. It has an open API for a reason, so developers can create tools to help them with their specific work and make features (like this) that don't ship with the base program. [Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io), which is now part of Sublime (you can install it from the menu), handles all the details of searching, downloading, installing, upgrading, and removing packages, pretty much seamlessly. I wouldn't be concerned at all about them, unless your work machine isn't networked, in which case you'd have to install and manage packages manually.

Answer (score 9):

Just go to:

```
View > Syntax > Open all with current extension as ... > JavaScript >
```

Then select JSX. It will open all JS as JSX, you can confirm it when you see the type of the file at the bottom right of the sublime window.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **JSCustom** package.
https://github.com/Thom1729/Sublime-JS-Custom

Open the command palette

*Win/Linux: ctrl+shift+p, Mac: cmd+shift+p*

Type Install Package Control, press enter and
search **JSCustom**

After installing **JSCustom**

choose: *Preferences → Package Settings → JS Custom → Rebuild Syntaxes*

Now reopen sublimeText. It will open any js file as JSX